# Find the ranges for each variable that give the largest amount of solutions

Tags: python, statistics

I'm not sure if there is a name for this kind of process. I have a dataset of entries with many input variables, each entry having an output of 0 or 1. I'm trying to find a good way to find ranges for each variable so that all the entries with those ranges have an output of 1. What would be the best way of finding the ranges with the largest number of entries with an output of 1?

Right now the process I thought of is sorting by each variable then tightening the range of the variable that has the lowest percentage of 1s near the max/min of that variable.

for example (3 inputs, 4th column is output):

```
[1.2, 6.0, -9.2, 0]
[1.4, 3.6,  3.2, 1]
[1.7, 3.8, -4.2, 0]
[2.2, 7.0, -3.3, 1]
[4.7, 3.4, -8.9, 1]
[4.9, 3.4, -8.9, 1]
```

The best ranges would be A (2.2 to 4.9) B (3.4 to 7.0) C (-8.9 to -3.3) which has three entries.
Sorting by the first variable, you could remove the entries that have values less than 2.2 in order to end up with only entries that have an output of 1.
(In reality there would be much more variables and entries)

Does this type of process have a name and is there a better way of doing it? Thank you!

Comment: A short example seems required to make you question more explicit

Comment: oh yeah you're right, added one

Answer (score 0):

Follow below code to get min & max for each variable where output=1; Need to check on large amount of data to gain more confidence if this is what required...

```
import pandas as pd

lst=[[1.2, 6.0, -9.2, 0],
[1.4, 3.6,  3.2, 1],
[1.7, 3.8, -4.2, 0],
[2.2, 7.0, -3.3, 1],
[4.7, 3.4, -8.9, 1],
[4.9, 3.4, -8.9, 1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=list('ABC')+["Output"])
df0 = df[df["Output"] == 0]
df1 = df[df["Output"] == 1]

lst_min_value,lst_max_value=[],[]
df2 = df.copy()

for col in df.columns[:-1]:
    max_0 = df0[col].max()
    min_1 = df1[col].min()
    min_val = max(max_0,min_1)
    
    min_value = df[df[col] > min_val][col].min()
    max_value = df1[col].max()

    df2 = df2[(df2[col] >= min_value) & (df2[col] <= max_value)]

for col in df2.columns[:-1]:
    print("Range for",col,":",df2[col].min(),df2[col].min())

# Output;
Range for A : 2.2 2.2
Range for B : 7.0 7.0
Range for C : -3.3 -3.3
```

Hope this Helps...

Comment: This won't remove all the 0s if there are 1s blocking. I tweaked the example to show

Comment: I'm trying to rule out all the inputs that are likely to lead to 0 outputs

Comment: May I know what shall be the expected output for edited input ?

Comment: Trying to produce a range for each variable where when applied to lst, only entries with an output of 1 remain. (the 4th column is the output)

Comment: @TNTOutburst edited the code.. got these ranges... is it what required ?

Comment: Those ranges do remove all 0s, but only one entry remains that fits the ranges. If range for A : 2.2 4.9 and B and C ranges are not changed, then all zeros would be removed while leaving three entries

Comment: Then it seems like, for all 3 columns (A,B,C) the range is same only... 2.2 to 2.2 , 7.0 to 7.0 & -3.3 to -3.3 respectively... correct ?

Comment: Those ranges only fit the 4th entry, when it is possible to find ranges that fit more than one entry. I'm trying to find ranges that fit as many entries as possible while having all of them have an output of 1.